# How do I whitelist Adobe Air applications in the panel?

Tags: unity, adobe-air

I know that for an application to show up in the systray I have to add it to the list using this command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

followed by a list of the applications. How can I add Adobe Air applications like Tweetdeck to the list? I tried using:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Wine', 'Tucan', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'AdobeAir', 'Tweetdeck']"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think $ gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist “['all']“ would work, but I don't want to allow all icons, only those in the list, until they get indicator support.

Comment: I use the way you quoted (and said that didn't work) and it works just fine. 

You have to logout to make it work , have you done that?

If that's not the case, their name might not be the one you used , try looking at "alacarte" what their name is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `TweetDeck` (note the capital "D") worked for me, but I had to restart Unity first:

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `unity`  and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: you don't need `--replace`