# Adobe Air application not showing an icon in Unity's notification area

Tags: unity, indicator, adobe-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I whitelist Adobe Air applications in the panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38635/how-do-i-whitelist-adobe-air-applications-in-the-panel)

I have installed Saezuri Twitter client on Adobe Air but when I run it, Unity's notification area doesn't show any icon for the same, as is shown by default in GNOME Shell as well as Xubuntu.

Comment: BUMP..anybody having a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute in a terminal: `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`